# Swift error on Windows: invalidManifestFormat: Missing or empty JSON output from manifest compilation

Tags: swift, windows

I've installed Swift 5.6.1 on my Windows 10 machine, including all the necessary Visual Studio components, but I can't seem to build anything. Even just running the following set of commands in git bash results in an error:

```sh
mkdir swiftTest
cd swiftTest
swift package init --type executable
swift build
```

Specifically, the `swift build` command gives the following errors:

```
warning: Failed creating default cache location, Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "(null)"
'swiftTest': error: invalidManifestFormat("Missing or empty JSON output from manifest compilation for swiftTest", diagnosticFile: nil)
```

The error message seems surprisingly rare -- the top google results were the source of the program that generated that error, and an unrelated error with similar wording  from a ReactJS application.
Do I just have to add some flags to the `swift build` command, or is there something else wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case what fixed it was invoking the command from a Visual Studio Developer Command prompt.

Comment: Huh, you're right. It worked just fine there, but not other terminals. I wonder what gives.

Comment: It works from my Java tests infrastructure but doesn't work via maven command.

Answer (score 0):

My experience doesn't exactly match, but I had a similar issue when trying to add a dependency of Gate Engine, which reported a lengthy message describing and **"invalid manifest"** issue.

For a simple "Hello" build, I had failed to turn on developer mode", and this solved my first problem. The second issue for the "invalid manifest error when bringing in the Gate Engine dependency was, the improper order of install of VS and Swift. **I had installed Swift first.**

If you don't know the order you followed and you have VS installed, uninstall Swift and install it again. You also might need to make sure you did a first time run of VS. If you are working in a terminal, close it and reopen terminal. (Do the same thing with VS Code).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34699481)